# how to print a table in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

i had following codes to print a table

```
public void print(final Node node) {
    Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    if (job != null) {
        boolean success = job.printPage(node);
        if (success) {
            job.endJob();
        }
    }
}
```

on button click

```
print(table);
```

but it doesn't print all columns it cuts half of table and print the half table.

I want to print the complete table. Is there any other codes to print a complete table.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how large your `Node` (i.e. `Table`) is at printing time. If you resize your table to all columns, then it will print all of them.

Same thing goes with the `snapshot` API for `Node`.

**Edit 1**: As [this article mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738106/print-contents-of-javafx-tableview), the table region must fit the printed page.

Comment: but when i was programing in java application there was no issue of half cut table print it has started when i started programing in javafx. my javafx table contains 8 columns but it print of 4. so can you help me how can i print my all columns.

Comment: @user3829658 Did you see the other article?

Comment: does this code `   PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
   if(printerJob.showPrintDialog(primaryStage.getOwner()) && printerJob.printPage(yourNode))
       printerJob.endJob();` will work for me