# Printing the ListView using javafx PrinterJob

Tags: javafx

Using JavaFX printer job when I  try to print ListView by default it will take snapshot and it will save the ListView as pdf file but the additional data which will come when you scroll down the ListView ,how it can be printed?my requirement is to print all string values which are added in ListView of JavaFX??

Comment: Please include code when asking technical questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print contents of JavaFx TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738106/print-contents-of-javafx-tableview)

Comment: You basically, have to take a snapshot and print it. Then scroll down to the next list of data. Then print that.  Continue this process until all the data is printed.

Comment: That entire process has to be done by the code. I was looking for that...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

//Created Button which will print the string generated in text area:

```
 Button printTextBtn = new Button("Print Text");
```

//Setting an event handler for the button:

```
printTextBtn.setOnAction(e -> print(text));
```

//text is an object of text area Example: TextArea text = new TextArea();
//You'll use your list object here at the place of (text)  in which your file is //being displayed after choosing from filechooser

//Here is a method that will invoke when the button is clicked.

```
private void print(Node node) {


  System.out.println("Creating a printer job...");

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    if (job != null) {
      System.out.println(job.jobStatusProperty().asString());

      boolean printed = job.printPage(node);
      if (printed) {
        job.endJob();
      } else {
        System.out.println("Printing failed.");
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("Could not create a printer job.");
    }

  }
```

Comment: that code will just take a snapshot of current Pane view and can be saved to PDF ,, here problem is i have ListView in pane if i pass pane node to print then the list of data which will come when u scroll down the scroll bar is not getting printed.